# C: Merge Sort for linked list, merged subarray not captured correctly in sort function

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, mergesort

Based on the pseudocode on Wikipedia's site for Merge Sort, I can get down to the base case of one node that merges correctly into a list of two nodes.  However, the merged portion get reversed I think when they move back up the recursive chain.

I am using a Makefile:

```
sort: main.c sort.c
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o $@ main.c sort.c ll.c
```

I am using a list header struct that contains a head pointer and tail pointer.  Head points to the first node and tail to the last.
The merge function is working but here is the sort function.

```
void list_sort(list_t *list)
{
printf("in sort 1\n");

    //base case of 0 or 1 element
    if (list->head == NULL || list->head->next == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    list_t *sublistA = list_create();
    assert(sublistA);
    list_t *sublistB = list_create();
    assert(sublistB);

    int len = Length(list);
    int mid = (len) / 2;
    printf("mid is %d\n", mid);
    int i = 0;
    element_t *current = list->head;
    //make sublists
    while (i < len) {
        if (i < mid) {  
            printf("append sublistA\n");
            list_append(sublistA, current->val);
        } else {
            printf("append sub B\n");
            list_append(sublistB, current->val);
        }
        i++;
        current = current->next;    
    }
    list_print(sublistA);
    list_print(sublistB);

    printf("going to sort A\n");
    list_sort(sublistA);

    printf("going to sort B\n");
    list_sort(sublistB);
    //this was just added to capture returned list from merge
    list_t* capture = NULL;
    assert(capture);//the assertion failed
    capture = merge(sublistA, sublistB);
    }
```

Edit:
Assertion failed so I switched to:

```
list_t* capture = list_create();
    assert(capture);

    capture = merge(sublistA, sublistB);
```

I am certain that it is not being captured correctly from printf statements in main, merge and sort.

Here is the output to command line that shows the unintended reversal:

```
/* left and right lists to merge://at the start of the merge function
{ 8, }
{ 7, }
in merge while 1
in merge else 1
{ 7, }
final result
{ 7, 8, }//yay!  this is the last line of merge function
in merge//came right back again to merge
left and right lists to merge:
{ 9, }
{ 8, 7, }//doh!*/
```

Edit:  Here is the merge function:

```
list_t *merge(list_t *left, list_t *right) {
    printf("in merge\n");
    list_t *result = list_create();
    assert(result);

    element_t *curr1 = left->head;
    element_t *curr2 = right->head;
    //list_t *result = list_create();
    printf("left and right lists to merge: \n");
    list_print(left);
    list_print(right);

    while (curr1 != NULL && curr2 != NULL) {
printf("in merge while 1\n");
        if (curr1->val <= curr2->val) {
            list_append(result, curr1->val);
            printf("merge while 1 if\n");
            curr1 = curr1->next;
            //curr2 = curr2->next;
        }
        else //curr1->val > curr2->val
        {
            printf("in merge else 1\n");
            list_append(result, curr2->val);
            curr2 = curr2->next;
        }
    }
    list_print(result);

    //leftovers need to be allocated
    while (curr1 != NULL) {
        list_append(result, curr1->val);
        curr1 = curr1->next;
    }

    while (curr2 != NULL) {
        list_append(result, curr2->val);
        curr2 = curr2->next;
    }

    //printf("curr1->val is %d\n", curr1->val);
    //printf("curr2->val is %d\n", curr2->val);
    list_destroy(left);
    list_destroy(right);
    printf("final result\n");
    list_print(result);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Provide [mcve].

Comment: There are many unreferenceable functions in the current code.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that is out of scope because of encapsulation.  the output has also been posted.

Comment: Can you post your entire code? At a minimum, your `struct` definitions and `list_create` and especially `list_append`. I believe I see your problem in your merge but would need to see `list_append` to be sure

Comment: @Nobu Again, Provide [mcve]. Currently [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is not satisfied.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I post the functions in the .h and .c files, I could get in trouble at school because those were assignments.  However, they passed the autograder so I am fairly certain that they are doing what they are supposed to do.

Comment: In that case, I think that You can do it yourself until the end.

Comment: The wiki pseudo code for top down merge sort for linked lists is very inefficient. The [wiki bottom up merge sort for linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) is much better. If you really want a top down merge sort for linked list, I suggest looking elsewhere (other than wiki).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that your `merge` function works by destructively modifying the input lists: you take the two lists as input, produce a new, merged list as output, and then return the resulting list. However, in your `list_sort` function, you aren't capturing the returned new list, and therefore you aren't updating the provided input list to hold the newly-sorted sequence. Try capturing the return value from `merge` and using it to update the input list parameter.

Comment: Well noted.  I'm going to give that a shot again.  I might have captured it incorrectly before.

Comment: I was getting, `"warning: variable ‘capture’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     list_t* capture = NULL;` until I used `list_t* capture =list_create()`.  Still does not work but your assessment was correct.  Thank you.

Comment: Well, you'll have to actually do something with that variable rather than just declaring it. :-) Think about what it contains and what your function says it's going to do with its argument.

Comment: My best guess at this moment is that `capture` contains the address to a header containing  `head` and `tail` pointers initialized to `NULL`  But then it gets re-assigned to the returning `list_t` pointer from merge.  `printf` statements indicate that capture is working correctly.  However, do I now have a memory leak for that header (containing `head` and `tail`) ?  Also, when merge is called again, it still reverses!

Comment: @Nobu - merge() returns a created and merged list, so that line should be `list t* capture = merge(...)`. list_sort() should return capture, and the two calls to merge should be changed to `sublistA = list_sort(sublistA);` and `sublistB = list_sort(sublistB);` . On a side note, this is a really inefficient method, meant to be a very crude example of top down merge sort in the wiki article.